# animate angular route transition and autoscroll to top

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use route in AngularJS and want a fade in/out transition between pages. I also want to have each page scrolled to top on a page change. I follow this technique to get this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfLcx/3/

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#/link1">Link1</a>
    <a href="#/link2">Link2</a>
</div>

....

<div class="ng-view" autoscroll></div>

angular.module('main', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/link1', {controller: '', templateUrl: 'link1.html'})
        .when('/link2', {controller: '', templateUrl: 'link2.html'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/link1'});
});
.directive('myScroll', function($rootScope, $anchorScroll) {
    return function(scope, element) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
           $anchorScroll(); 
        });
    };
});
```

This fiddle was created based on this issues thread:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6718

As you can see in the fiddle, and which is also noted, but unsolved, in the issue thread, the problem with this solution is that on navigation between page Link1 -> page Link2, page Link1 is first scrolled to top before the page Link2 transition happens. This behavior I do not know to get around. I would like Page Link1 to fade out without scrolling to top but Page Link2 to still fade in scrolled to top.

Does anyone know a solution for this issue?
thanks!
/o

**** EDIT ******

The reply below led me into using the $location events, if someone else never hits this issue this is how I ended up solving it:

A fader class on my view container:

```
<div class="fader" ng-view></div>
```

In my app I check for locationChangeStart and before scolling to top I hide the view:

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $anchorScroll) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
    jQuery('.fader').hide();
    $anchorScroll();
  });
});
```

In css a subtle fade:

```
/* The starting CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fader.ng-enter {
  transition:0.1s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fader.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}

/* The starting CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fader.ng-leave {
    /*transition:0s linear all;*/
  opacity:1;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fader.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Since I'm new to Angular this is probably not the best way to do it, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery animate to scroll to top on page transition. On angular app run config add listener for locationChangeSuccess and then use jquery animate to scroll to top

```
.run(function ($rootScope) {
                $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event) {
            jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        });

    });
```

Comment: This wasn't really what I asked for, I do not want an animated scroll to the top. However, it lead me into using the location events so thanks for that.